# ERROR 266: Inconsistent Datatype: TIMESTAMP type is incompatible with INT type SAP HANA

Tags: database, timestamp, integer, hana

I am trying to transfer a source table A on SAP HANA to another target table B.

Both tables have the same structure below; they both have a column `LASTUPDATE` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`, but when I try to execute

```
Insert into TABLE B (Select BASE1,BASE2,LASTUPDATE from TABLE A)
```

there is this error:

> ERROR 266: Inconsistent Datatype: TIMESTAMP type is incompatible with INT type

Structure of table A:

[image: The structure of SOURCE TABLE]

Structure of table B:

[image: The structure of TARGET TABLE]

It is maybe a bug, do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

It looks like it is reading `LASTUPDATE` on TARGET as an INT, but I checked the structure it is of type `TIMESTAMP` and Modified it to type `Date` and `To_SecondDate`, I have the same error it is read as INT.

```
insert into wctversion (SELECT base1,base2,base3,base4,lastupdate,
schname,status,updateuser FROM TMP_wctversion)
```

It shows this ERROR:

> Could not execute 'insert into wctversion (SELECT base1,base2,base3,base4,lastupdate,schname,status,updateuser FROM ...'
>   SAP DBTech JDBC: [266]: inconsistent datatype: TIMESTAMP type is incompatible with INT type: line 1 col 57 (at pos 56)

Comment: As far as I can see, the position of the columns is not the same, so it tries putting the timestamp (column lastupdate, position 8) into the integer (column status, position 8)

Comment: @legxis can you convert your comment into an answer? (just complete it a little bit to explain how SQL `INSERT ... SELECT` works, but it's definitely the right answer; you should also highlight that the OP didn't pay attention to the `POSITION` value of columns)

Comment: **Always** specify the target columns `insert into wctversion (col1, col2, col3) select ....`

Comment: Thank you ! It worked very well ! It was indeed a position problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name you have not specified the traget fields, so the system is trying to allocate the fields sequentially.

In your case that means you're trying to insert LASTUPDATE into BASE3 - hence the conversion error.

You should have:

```sql
INSERT INTO B ("BASE1", "BASE2", "LASTUPDATE") (SELECT "BASE1", "BASE2", "LASTUPDATE" FROM A)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked very well ! It was indeed a position problem :)